# How to print output to a variable instead of stdout?

Tags: r

I want to convert an object to a string representation of it in the same way that the `print()` function does. But I also want to store that string in a variable instead of sending it to stdout. For example:

When I enter `print(mtcars)` it will print the data frame in a pretty way. But when I use the `toString` method it will convert to a string like: `c(21, 21, 22.8, ...), c(6, 6, 4, ....), ...` (I used `...` to shorten the output).

But I would like the string to be in the same format as the `print()` function. It would be nice if there was an `sprint` function that takes any variable as input. There exists `sprintf`, but then I will have to know the type of the object before hand.

I saw something about using `results <- capture.output(...)` but it seemed too complex. There should be a easy way to do that.

Comment: You've answered your own question; that's what `capture.output` does, e.g. `mtcars_lines <- capture.output(mtcars)` will store a character vector of lines captured from the print method of `mtcars`.

Answer (score 3):

The comment of @alistaire was right. I can simply use capture.output. But I still need to paste the lines together. So my final solution is:

```
paste(capture.output(mtcars), collapse="\n")
```